# Как получить доступ к блоку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему. 
У меня есть код

```
<script>
        var item = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(items) %>');
        var card_items = [];
        item.forEach(function(item){
            console.log(item._id);
            $('.items').append('<a href="#" onclick=""><li>' + item.title + '</li></a>' + '<div id="' + item._id + '"></div>');

            var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
            inputElement.type = "button"
            inputElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
                AddToCart(item._id);
            });
             $('#'+ item._id).append(inputElement)​;
        });
        function AddToCart(id){
            console.log(id);
        }
    </script>
```

`

Проблема в том что я не могу получить доступ к диву, сгенерированому в этой строке

```
$('.items').append('<a href="#" onclick=""><li>' + item.title + '</li></a>' + '<div id="' + item._id + '"></div>');
```

для отображения там кнопки, а в этой строчке выводит ошибку:

```
$('#'+ item._id).append(inputElement)​;
```

такого вида: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас там символ &#8203 стоит вот здесь `$('#'+ item._id).append(inputElement)​;`перед знаком ';'.

Удалите его и ваш код [будет работать](https://plnkr.co/edit/7rrVhedNR4y1Q2qtKFZE?p=preview).